# langchain and python-docx mac m1 error : symbol not found in flat namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-docx, py-langchain

Python Version : 3.9

System Version : Mac M1 12.5.1

I have the following problems in the process of using langchain

Sample code :

```py
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loader = DirectoryLoader('./data/', glob='**/*.md')
    documents = loader.load()
```

The following abnormal information is prompted

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/langchain/text01.py", line 5, in <module>
    documents = loader.load()
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/directory.py", line 84, in load
    raise e
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/directory.py", line 78, in load
    sub_docs = self.loader_cls(str(i), **self.loader_kwargs).load()
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/unstructured.py", line 70, in load
    elements = self._get_elements()
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/langchain/document_loaders/unstructured.py", line 102, in _get_elements
    from unstructured.partition.auto import partition
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/unstructured/partition/auto.py", line 9, in <module>
    from unstructured.partition.doc import partition_doc
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/unstructured/partition/doc.py", line 7, in <module>
    from unstructured.partition.docx import partition_docx
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/unstructured/partition/docx.py", line 6, in <module>
    import docx
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docx/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from docx.api import Document  # noqa
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docx/api.py", line 14, in <module>
    from docx.package import Package
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docx/package.py", line 9, in <module>
    from docx.opc.package import OpcPackage
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docx/opc/package.py", line 9, in <module>
    from docx.opc.part import PartFactory
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docx/opc/part.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .oxml import serialize_part_xml
  File "/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/docx/opc/oxml.py", line 12, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/zhangsan/project/python/test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/lxml/etree.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (_exsltDateXpathCtxtRegister)
```

According to the above exception information, when I checked the "import docx" step, I entered the python command line environment and executed the code manually.

```
import docx
```

It is found that the same error message as the above exception is triggered.

Comment: @BentheCoder  Thank you for your advice. I'm sorry for my wrong description. I edited the problem again.

Comment: Your question quality is much better. Thank you! I would up vote your question, only I've reached my daily vote limit of 40 votes.

Comment: Just suggested an edit to your post for the moderators to deal with: adding another tag to your question, the [tag:python] one.  When you have the [tag:python-3.x] tag in your list of tags, you should also include the [tag:python] tag.